# Is it possible to make custom implementation for RememberMeAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

greetings all
i am using spring security 3.0.2
and i want when a remembered user requests a page
after his token is being authenticated (onAuthenticationSuccess)
do some coding before landing him to his request 
i got the idea to provide a custom implementation of the RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
but i don't know how to do so, so can anyone tell me
or if there's a better way to do what i am trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can [subscribe](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events) to `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` and check whether `authentication` is `RememberMeAuthenticationToken`.

Comment: @ axtavt what about the custom implementation for spring existing filter, is it possible ?

Comment: It's possible, but I think it would be more complex than the proposed solution, so you should have a reason for doing so.

Comment: It is possible to do what you describe.  Did you already figure it out/resolve it?  If not I can help you out with this.

Comment: we need a little more guide here, please.